# Conceptual question about log-linear analysis

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, log-linear

I have measured the binary occurrence of three types of events on multiple days. Theory suggests that these events are not independent and should occur on the same days more than would be expected based on their marginal probabilities alone. To test this hypothesis, I believe I can use log-linear modeling to predict the count of each combination of events.

**Question 1:** Is log-linear modeling the correct approach here?

```
# Example data
df <- data.frame(
    A = c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE),
    B = c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE),
    C = c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE),
    Y = c(911, 44, 538, 456, 3, 2, 43, 279)
)
```

If the four events are A, B, and C, and my count variable is Y then I think I can specify the independence and saturated models with the following formulas:

```
mod0 <- glm(Y ~ A + B + C, data = df, family = poisson)
mod3 <- glm(Y ~ (A + B + C)^3, data = df, family = poisson)
```

**Question 2:** To test my hypothesis, am I correct in comparing the saturated model to a homogeneous associations model without the three-way interaction?

```
mod2 <- glm(Y ~ (A + B + C)^2, data = df, family = poisson)
aod <- anova(mod2, mod3)
#> Analysis of Deviance Table
#> 
#> Model 1: Y ~ (A + B + C)^2
#> Model 2: Y ~ (A + B + C)^3
#>   Resid. Df Resid. Dev Df Deviance
#> 1         1    0.37399            
#> 2         0    0.00000  1  0.37399
pchisq(0.37399, df = 1, lower.tail = FALSE)
#> [1] 0.5408374
```

**Question 3:** To extend this to more than three types of events, would I just increase the exponent (e.g., compare mod4 to mod3 for four event types)?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Could you please explain how your data frame represents "days"?  The meaning you attach to "independence" is ambiguous, so some clarification would be helpful.

Comment: @whuber Sure. The Y variable represents the frequency or count of days that had each combination of events. The first row, for instance, shows that 911 days had all three events occur (i.e., TRUE). I was under the impression that log-linear models in GLM required a conversion to frequencies or counts like this.

Comment: @whuber I will try to clarify my use of "independence." I mean that the same causal process is contributing to all three events, causing them to occur more frequently at the same time. So the TRUE-TRUE-TRUE cell of the three-way contingency table should be greater in frequency than would be expected if these events were occurring randomly and did not have this relationship.

Comment: Thank you.  The issue is that when data are collected over time, there often is an expectation that the results on one day will not be independent of results on preceding days.  If this is a possibility, we need to know, because it would indicate a completely different model.

Comment: Good point. I would say there is strong reason to think that days may be autocorrelated within event types. That is, events can and do last multiple days. Whether or not this autocorrelation also applies across event types is one of the questions I am hoping to explore.

Comment: To handle this correctly you will need to give us some more clues about what these events are.  At the level of abstraction you are using, you haven't provided enough information to address the problem appropriately.

Comment: My apologies. I was trying to be helpful in simplifying things but that backfired. I will update the question tonight with more details.

Comment: Given how different it is, I have made a new question rather than edit this one: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/368614/what-is-the-appropriate-analysis-for-this-type-of-repeated-measures-multi-binary