# What is the appropriate analysis for this type of repeated measures multi-binary data?

Tags: repeated-measures, multilevel-analysis, log-linear, finite-mixture-model, research-design

There is a popular theory within psychology that certain emotions will trigger "prototypical" facial expressions defined by the simultaneous contraction of specific facial muscles. For example, if a person experiences the emotion of surprise, then they should reflexively contract three specific muscles at the same time (causing the inner brow to raise, the outer brow to raise, and the upper eye lids to raise). There are similar predictions for other emotions as well, and the number of muscles that are proposed for each emotion ranges from 2 to 6 muscles.

I have videos of study participants having emotionally charged conversations, and have annotated every frame of these videos to indicate whether each relevant facial muscle is contracted or not. So, I have repeated binary measures (~2000 frames each per ~200 participants) and want to see if indeed the proposed combinations of muscles are more common than other non-proposed combinations or the "chance" co-occurrence of the relevant muscles (e.g., based on marginal probabilities).

**What would be an appropriate analysis to test this hypothesis?**

I believe that loglinear models can test the independence of categories and that these can be implemented in the generalized linear model (GLM). Furthermore, because I have repeated measures, I believe that I need to account for the clustering of video frames within participants. So I was thinking that I might be able to use generalized linear mixed effects modeling or multilevel GLM. Is this right, or would I need to do something else such as multilevel mixture modeling?

Please let me know if further information would be helpful and I will happily provide it.

Comment: So, wouldn't this be a test of proportions, i.e., proportion of the total that (x,y,z) occurs is higher than other proportion different than the triplet (x,y,z)? Or maybe you want to test whether the proportion occurs beyond a threshold, say 50% of the time?

Comment: Maybe I could calculate the probability of all three happening at once based on marginal probabilities and then use that as the threshold.

Comment: So you have a ( joint)prior?

Comment: So you have a ( joint)prior? EDIT: Or are you assumming a uniform distribution.

Comment: If I'm understanding your question correctly, you want to know if I think the video frames are independent or not. I think there is probably autocorrelation present since muscles will usually contract for multiple consecutive frames.

Comment: Yes, basically. I was thinking maybe compute P(x,y,z contract|  emotion w is experienced) to test for independence.